# Contigous allocation of memory for an array

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

As far as I understand, arrays are allocated contiguous blocks of memory. I wrote a program to test my understanding. It basically attaches a shared memory segment. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/shm.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 

int main () 
{
int segment_id; 
int* shared_memory; 
struct shmid_ds shmbuffer; 
int segment_size; 
const int
shared_segment_size = 4096; //one page size 

int *results;
int cpid=0;
int sum=0;


/* Allocate a shared memory segment.  */ 
segment_id = shmget (IPC_PRIVATE, shared_segment_size, 
             IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR); 

/* Attach the shared memory segment. Results now contain the starting address  */ 
results =shmat (segment_id, 0, 0);

printf("%p\n",&results);
printf("%p\n",&results[1]);
printf("%p\n",&results[2]);
printf("%p\n",&results[3]);


return 0; 
}
```

Here is the output:

```
0x7fffe4d62e40
0x7f6603987004
0x7f6603987008
0x7f660398700c
```

Can someone explain to me why the address of results[1] is:

```
0x7f6603987004
```

given that the address of results[0] is:

```
0x7fffe4d62e40
```

Shouldn't it be 0x7fffe4d62e44?
Am I missing something crucial?

Comment: `&results` is the address **of** the local pointer variable; not the address ***in*** the variable. Change it to `results`.

Comment: Note that `&results[0]` could be written as `results`, but `&results` is something entirely different. `&results` is the address of the pointer, not an address in the shared memory.

Comment: Okay. So, &results is returning to me the address to the pointer itself, isn't it? I think I got it. Thanks.

Comment: Its probably even easier to understand the pointer arithmetic if you lose all the subscripting and `&` usages *entirely*. Just use `result`, `result+1`, `result+2`, etc.. The pointer arithmetic will work out. Try it.

Comment: Did that right now. It is working. I think I need to revisit my basics.

Comment: @PrashantPandey No worries. Pointer arithmetic is always a little odd to people when they first encounter it. It comes by instinct very quickly. Keep at it.

Comment: Yeah man. Actually, I am returning to C after a long time working with Java. So, it is a bit odd. But I think I'll catch-up fast. Thanks @WhozCraig.

Comment: OT: How do you now that one_page_size = 4096?

Comment: I used getconf PAGE_SIZE command.

Comment: Ah, ok, you can do it programmatically using [getpagesize](https://linux.die.net/man/2/getpagesize)